# Почему объект не уничтожается, а если и уничтожается то только при завершении программы

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

небольшой код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SafeLibrary vlcCoreLibrary = new VlcCoreLibrary();
        SafeLibrary vlcLibrary = new VlcLibrary();

        string[] array = new string[] { "-vvv", "-I dummy" };

        IntPtr vlcInstance = vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcNew>().Invoke(array.Length, ((CStringArray)array).Handle);
        IntPtr vlcMediaPlayer = vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaPlayerNew>().Invoke(vlcInstance);
        IntPtr vlcMedia = vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaNewFromPath>().Invoke(vlcInstance, "file:///C:/Users/Reiko/Desktop/HARU%20NEMURI%20%E2%80%94%20Untitled.mp3");
        vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaPlayerSetMedia>().Invoke(vlcMediaPlayer, vlcMedia);

        if (vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaPlayerPlay>().Invoke(vlcMediaPlayer) == 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKeyInfo;

        while ((consoleKeyInfo = System.Console.ReadKey(false)).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaPlayerStop>().Invoke(vlcMediaPlayer);
        vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaRelease>().Invoke(vlcMedia);
        vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcMediaPlayerRelease>().Invoke(vlcMediaPlayer);
        vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcRelease>().Invoke(vlcInstance);
    }
}
```

В котором стоит обратить внимание на преобразование из массива строк в `CStringArray` класс.

```
vlcLibrary.GetInteropDelegate<VlcNew>().Invoke(array.Length, ((CStringArray)array).Handle);
```

В классе `CStringArray` есть `implicit` operator

```
public static implicit operator CStringArray(string[] strings)
{
    return new CStringArray(strings);
}
```

Как видно, ссылка на объект `CStringArray` нигде не хранится, при этом установлена точка остановки на финализатор/деструктор данного класса, и что интересное его вызов происходит только если нажать на <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Какая из причин может мешать уничтожить этот объект если ссылки на него не хранятся нигде?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самая простая причина - недетерминированность сборки мусора. GC собирает объект не в момент, когда на него пропадают ссылки, а позже, когда ему захочется собрать мусор.

Обычно сборка мусора запускается по достижению лимита поколения - когда при выделении нового объекта GC обнаруживает, что с момента последней сборки мусора выделено больше какого-то объёма памяти (около 256k). Так что пока вы не насоздаете достаточно много объектов - GC не будет ничего собирать.

И, кстати, ваш код написан небезопасно - после извлечения Handle и даже до вызова использующего его метода GC вполне может отработать, убить объект, и Handle станет невалиден. Объявите локальную переменную и заверните её в using.